# Updating fragment after returning from an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have set of `Foo` objects. I have an activity which contains a `ListFragment` listing all of them. Clicking an item on the list opens another activity containing fragments displaying the `Foo` details. From that activity I'm able to navigate to the third activity for editing the `Foo` details. The data is currently queried on the listing fragment and put into intent extras for usage in details fragments.

The problem is updating the data in the fragments in details and the list fragment, when I navigate back from the edit activity (when there are changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, one approach would be to make the underlying data set accessible to other activities in a more direct way, by using, say, a singleton class.

Comment: Covered in [Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3)